# Convert entities with ModelMapper

Tags: java, modelmapper

Source and destination entities have difference in  style of field-naming (underscore in one, camelCase - in another).
So, source:

```
 public class User {
    private String first_name;
}
```

Destination:

```
public class UserDto {
    private String firstName;
}
```

I have a task to convert entities by ModelMapper automatically - without handle mapping of fields (by getter-setter).

For this aim I tried to configure mapper as follows:

```
 ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration()
            .setSourceNameTokenizer(NameTokenizers.UNDERSCORE);
```

But this does not work

Comment: Private access via Reflection is problematic in Java 17 and following. If you want to avoid writing boilerplate code, just use `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations from Lombok on your classes. Or if you want only certain privates fields become accessible: on single field variables.

Answer (score 3):

By default, [field matching is disabled](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/configuration/), so you have to change flag in configuration.Since your fields are private, you must also include them in your setup:

```java
modelMapper.getConfiguration()
    .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
    .setFieldAccessLevel(AccessLevel.PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Well, `PRIVATE` most likely won't work with Java 17, the latest LTS version, used in Big Companies. So you will have to use getters and setters. I recommend Lombok @Getter and @Setter Annotations for that.

Answer (score 1):

As [already correctly answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67988188/6413377) by [M. Dudek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8653765/m-dudek) you need to enable the field access separately if you do not want to use getters/setters.

But in order to have it working in both directions you need to also **setDestinationNameTokenizer**:

```
modelMapper.getConfiguration()
    .setSourceNameTokenizer(NameTokenizers.UNDERSCORE)
    .setDestinationNameTokenizer(NameTokenizers.UNDERSCORE)
    .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
    .setFieldAccessLevel(AccessLevel.PRIVATE);
```

If willing to use getters/setters then this should be enough:

```
modelMapper.getConfiguration()
    .setSourceNameTokenizer(NameTokenizers.UNDERSCORE)
    .setDestinationNameTokenizer(NameTokenizers.UNDERSCORE):
```

Comment: But in @Andrew case, destination class don't have fields in `UNDERSCORE` format, so your solution can't work for him.